# Como iniciar o Jekyll com um tema já baixado

Tags: github, jekyll

Olá, pessoal.
Baixei o Jekyll e suas dependências e consegui criar um novo blog dando um `jekyll new novodoblog`, mas agora baixei um tema e queria criar um novo blog a partir dele. Dei um `jekyll serve` mas deu esse erro:

```
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-paginate or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
```

E não faço ideia de como resolver. 
Como posso iniciar um novo blog a partir de um tema já baixado? Ou se não, como posso resolver esse problema?

Desde já, obrigada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No terminal, vá até o diretório do blog e execute `bundle install` para instalar todas as dependências do jekyll.
Se mesmo assim não funcionar, instale diretamente o `jekyll-paginate` com `gem install jekyll-paginate`.

Se você estiver modificando seu projeto instalando um novo tema não esqueça de modificar o `Gemfile` alterando o nome/versão do tema antigo pelo novo.

Comment: Obrigada, Rafael. Consegui resolver o problema! :)